# Google account hacked: why was I still able to log in?

Tags: support, login, accounts

Days ago my Gmail account was hacked and destroyed. Google recovery wizard brought me nowhere. I am still counting the data I lost.

Anyway one good thing happened: as I went on Stack Overflow I was logged in, so I immediately went to user profile and put my new Gmail account.

In this way I still have my OpenID account.

It is not clear to me why I was logged in even if my Google account is dead. May be because of a cookie?

It is good I am still here anyway.

Comment: Did you still have an open tab somewhere with a SE site?

Comment: I don't know the details of SO's login system, but my understanding is "logged in to Stack Exchange" is independent from "logged in to my OpenID provider" - if SE carries on your session then it won't check with the OpenID provider

Comment: If you can't login, you can make a new account and request a dev to merge them for you, using the new account's login instead of the hacked account to login.

Comment: @UniversalElectricity I think you can't. To merge, you have to confirm both accounts. Which he can't since he didn't have the mail id